# FTP using Batch file

Tags: windows, ftp, batch-file, dos

i want to automate the task of uploading of a file at FTP site "uploads.google.com"
how can i achive this

Answer (score 1):

please see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269) for example

Answer (score 1):

One of the example is depicted as follows :

1. Prepare a file (say ftp_cmd.txt)with all the ftp commands to upload the files to our specific site
   as below:

---

binary
cd 
mput file.*

### bye

2. Now create a batch file with the following content:

ftp -i -v -s:

ex: ftp -i -v -s:ftp_cmd.txt updates.google.com

Now, when you execute this batch file, it will put all files with format file.* to the specified directory.